# Why does my dialog show up lower on the screen the first time, and higher on each time after?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, modal-dialog

I am building an MVC 4 app with lots of cells in a table which the user will click for additional data about the contents of that cell, so I pop up a modal jQuery dialog. I don't claim to have done this correctly but I have an Ajax form that contains nothing but a hidden field to send off the id of the clicked cell contents to the controller.

```
@Html.Hidden("selectedStatusId")
```

Then on clicking I get the id and put it into that hidden:

```
$(".statusCell").click(function () {
    var statusId = this.id;
    document.getElementById("getStatusDataForm").selectedStatusId.value = statusId;
    $("#getStatusDataForm").submit();
    $("#StatusData").dialog("open");
});
```

The next to the last line is submitting the form which returns a partial to the empty div:

```
<div id="StatusData" title="Status Details" class="selectedStatusDetail" style="display: none"></div>
```

Then I configure my dialog:

```
$(function () {
  $("#StatusData").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false,
    draggable: true,
    width: 800,
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 100
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 100
    },
    create: function (event, ui) {
        // Center the dialog each time it re-opens
        $(this).dialog('widget')
            .css({ position: 'fixed' })
            .position({ my: 'center', at: 'center', of: window, collision: 'fit' });
    },
    open: function (event, ui) {
        // Remove the closing 'x' from the toolbar and replace it with the text 'Close'
        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close')
            .removeClass("ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
            .html('<span style="float:right; margin-right: 10px; font-weight: normal;">Close</span>');
    },
});
```

So the first time I click on one of the cells the dialog displays 107px below where it displays every time from then on. Other than that it works perfectly. 
I have read about how you don't want to display before the dialog is loaded and I suspect that might be happening since the call to the db is async and I create the dialog before I know I get the data back. But this is the only way I have been able to get all of the rest to work. 
Do I need to refactor the whole mess or is there a fix?

Comment: could you post the ajax function or recreate this in a fiddle?  I think you're on the right track, and if so, the easiest solution would be to wrap whatever you're adding via ajax in a div width fixed dimensions.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. The problem is I don't know the size of the returned data and I don't want an over-sized dialog or scrolling if I can help it.